# Change the color of primefaces Scheduler Event

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces(3.0) scheduler component.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/schedule.jsf

As we can see here there there are some events created with color
 blue.

Now I want to change the color of these events, on the basis of
 uniqueness. As a example for each empolyee there will be a unique ID
 associated.

So for lets say for employee ID 1 Events color will be blue, for ID 2
 events color will be red and so on.

how can I apply colors to these number of events from backing bean ?
 Any clue....

I am able to change the background color for scheduler in this way, but dont have any idea about how to change the color of events ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you need, add style class and data in the same event.

Example:

```
String id="2";
DefaultScheduleEvent evento = new DefaultScheduleEvent("titule", new Date(), new Date(), id);
evento.setStyleClass("event-close");
```

In the CSS, Damian's response is good.

Comment: i have color saved in db, how can i give color to that styleclass?

Answer (score 4):

There's a constructor for DefaultScheduleEvent that takes a CSS class as parameter:

```
eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();  
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Event for employee 1", new Date(), laterToday(), "emp1"));
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Event for employee 2", tomorrow(), laterTomorrow(), "emp2"));
```

emp1 and emp2 are the style classes.

For PrimeFaces 3.0 add the following css to your style sheet:

```
.emp1 .fc-event-skin {
    background: red;
}
.emp2 .fc-event-skin {
   background: green;
 }
```

For other PrimeFaces versions, see the other answers

Comment: for primefaces 4 or 5 a different css is needed
see my answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688617/primefaces-schedule-event-color-is-not-working-after-replacing-primefaces-jar-3

Answer (score 1):

apply this code when use primefaces 4.0

```
eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();  
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Event for employee 1", new Date(), laterToday(), "emp1"));
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Event for employee 2", tomorrow(), laterTomorrow(), "emp2"));
```

emp1 and emp2 are the style classes. Then add the following css to your style sheet:

```
.emp1 .fc-event-inner {
    background: red;
}
.emp2 .fc-event-inner {
   background: green;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Primefaces 7.0 the CSS selector needs to be different. You should use `.fc-bg`

Work with the follow CSS code:

```
.specialEvent .fc-bg {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Setting the style from the javacode stays the same

Answer (score 0):

You can define style classes in stylesheet and in backing bean set style class to `DefaultScheduleEvent` instance with method:

```
public void setStyleClass(String styleClass)
```

Comment: how to give this class background-color got from db?

Answer (score -1):

After setting styleClass in code, coloring did not work for me in PrimeFaces 5.2 as described above. Finally I got it working with the important modifier:

```
a.emp1 {
   background: #D0525D !important;
   border-color: #932c39!important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use !important unless really, really, really needed. Better is to make your selector more specific... (there is e.g. no explicit indication this is only for a schedule component, the answer with the '.fc-event-inner' in the selector is better)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I totally agree but I tried to use different classes (even listing all what I saw in inspection details) but nothing worked. Also I ensured that my css is loaded as last. That's why I added my solution - the others did not work for me. I'm using Spark theme.

Comment: Does spark them use !important itself? That might explain things